# How to handle events of a component that is dynamically mounted?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component that is defined as:

**Calculator.vue**

```html
    <template>
       ...
    </template>
```

```js
    <script>
    export default {
      data: function () {
        return {
          value: 0,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        ...
        insert() {
          this.$emit('insert',Number(this.value))
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

Now I have another component that inflates a `Popup` which contains my `Calculator` component

**Main.vue**

```html
    <template>
       ...
    </template>
```

```js
    <script>
    import Calculator from "../../ui/Calculator.vue";
    export default {
      data: function () {
        return {};
      },
      methods: {
        openCalculator() {
          this.$popup("append", {
            component: Calculator,
          });
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

The Popup component is just third-party component that acts like a component wrapper. So I need to have it always included in my **App.vue**:

```html
    <template>
      <div id="app">
        <router-view />
        <VuePopupPlugin :config="popupDefaultConfig" />
      </div>
    </template>
```

```js
    <script>
    import Vue from "vue";
    import CiaoVuePopup from "ciao-vue-popup";
    Vue.use(CiaoVuePopup);
    export default {
      name: "app",
      ...
    };
    </script>
```

How can I handle the `'insert'` event of the inflated `Calculator` from my `Main` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `v-on="$listeners"`

Actually I suggest using Vuex.  But if not, here is how you can do this.

In the middle component `Popup`, catch the event from its child `Calculator`.  If it's a dynamic component, that works too.  Don't do anything with the event except bubble it up to `Main`.  That's what `v-on="$listeners"` does:

```html
<!-- In `Popup` -->
<Calculator v-on="$listeners"></Calculator>
```

Then in `Main`, create the listener as though `Calculator` was its direct child, and place it on the middle component, `Popup`:

```html
<!-- In `Main` -->
<VuePopupPlugin @insert="insert" :config="popupDefaultConfig" />
```

```js
methods: {
  insert() {
    console.log('Woo inserting');
  }
}
```

It works because `$listeners` in `Popup` grabs all the listeners from its parent, `Main`, and applies them to its child, `Calculator`, as though the middle component wasn't in the way.  You can chain multiple middle components by using `v-on="$listeners"` on all of them.

Here's a demo:

```js
Vue.component('Calculator', {
    template: `
  <div class="calc">
    CALCULATOR:
    <button @click="insert">Insert</button>
  </div>`,
  data: function () {
    return {
      value: 1000,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    insert() {
      this.$emit('insert', Number(this.value))
    },
  }
})

Vue.component('Popup', {
  template: `
  <div class="popup">
    POPUP:
    <component :is="comp" v-on="$listeners"></component>
  </div>
  `,
    data() {
      return {
        comp: 'Calculator'
      }
    }
});

/***** APP *****/
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
        someEventData: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    insert(eventData) {
        this.someEventData = eventData;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.calc, .popup {
  padding: 24px;
}
.calc {
  background: #dddddd;
}
.popup {
  background: #FF99FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  ROOT
  <Popup @insert="insert"></Popup>
  From grandchild (calculator): {{ someEventData }}
</div>
```

You can use Vuex to avoid this situation by having all components emit to and retrieve data from one centralized store.

Comment: Thanks, as you suggested, I ended up using Vuex to manage the problem

Comment: You're welcome, probably a good choice.  Vuex is a far better pattern in most situations.  This can be nice for very closely related components I guess.